# Windows Xperia excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 50 work books each work book is for 1 subcontract operative. Also each operatives work book has 52 sheets one for each week. I need to extract the same cell (£ payment total) to list the weekly totals for each operative on to a master report sheet in a master workbook. 
Each operative work book file name is the operatives name.
Each work sheet tab name is week 1, week 2, etc in each operative work book.
Please help thanks.

Eg goal report list from each work book:

- Jack week 1 £500
- Bill week 1 £300
- Ted  week 1 £600

I know how to pull the same cell from each work sheet in the same workbook to list on a report sheet in the same workbook using =INDIRECT("'"&A7&"'!E16")
A7 being the column ref where each sheet is named on the report sheet.
E16 is the cell ref of the value.

But not from multiple work books to list on a report sheet into workbook.

Regards, 
Chris.

Comment: This is a problem for VBA.  What have you tried?  We'll need a lot more specific information to help you.